# Detect difference between Cut and Copy in Swing

Tags: java, swing, clipboard

I'm using Java 6, it's highly unlikely we'll go to Java 7.

My Swing application should handle pasting files cut or copied from external sources (be it Windows Explorer, Free Commander, or what have you...)

It works pretty well, with one important exception: I have no way of knowing if a file was cut or copied, nor is there a way to tell the system clipboard that the paste was successful. Ideally, of course, the system should handle it, but it doesn't seem to do it. If I could at least tell if it's a cut or a copy, I could delete the cut files myself, but I couldn't find anything along those lines, either.

Right now, cut works just like copy.

How do I detect whether the user uses cut or copy?

Comment: *"Oh yeah, before I forget,"*  Did you forget to ask a question, or mark it with a '?'?

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/cutpaste.html

Comment: hmm .. just as you, I would expect the OS to handle the actual cut/copy - could you show a quick SSCCE that demonstrates it not doing as expected?